# How can I find the difference between each row and the top row in each group?[python]

Tags: python, function, pivot-table, grouping, diff

This is a sample of my real dataset.

```
data = {'CarNo': [888, 81, 16, 62, 31, 23, 777, 23, 777, 31, 888, 62, 81, 16, 888, 31, 81, 62, 16, 23],
        'LapTime': [119628, 117170, 119846, 117178, 119516, 117915, 116964, 116683, 117169, 118919, 119227, 117789, 117674, 116914, 116333, 120027, 116403, 117351, 116557, 117107],
       'LAPS': [147.0, 147.0, 147.0, 147.0, 147.0, 146.0, 121.0, 56.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 54.0, 54.0, 54.0, 123.0, 123.0, 123.0, 123.0, 123.0, 122.0],
       'UpdateTime': [162047732, 162047732, 162047732, 162047732, 162047732, 162047732, 162047732, 125626988, 125626988, 125626988, 125626988, 125626988, 125626988, 125626988, 151851068, 151851068, 151851068, 151851068, 151851068, 151851068],
        'rank': [6.0, 2.0, 7.0, 3.0, 5.0, 4.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 7.0, 5.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0, 7.0, 2.0, 5.0, 3.0, 4.0]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

I want to groupby according to the "UpdateTime" then find the gap between each row and Rank one in each group.
From other questions here, I did something like bellow. but it is not very clever and I am also loosing my first row.
Please help.

```
def diff_to_top(df,colA):
    pos=sub.columns.get_loc(colA)
    gap = sub.iloc[1:, pos] - sub.iat[0, pos]
    return gap

sub = df.set_index(['UpdateTime','rank','LAPS'])
sub.sort_index(inplace=True, ascending=True)

diff_to_top(sub,'LapTime')
```

Comment: "but it is not very clever and I am also loosing my first row" What should appear in the first row? If we take the difference of the first row and the first row, the result should be zero, correct? Is it useful to have this in the output?

Comment: it is not zero, it is gone! I have to keep this row. I have to have a ZERO for the row rank=1, then some negative time on the other rows of each group of groupby(because the Rank=1 is the car with the fastest speed)

Comment: Oh. It is gone because of the `1:` in `sub.iloc[1:, pos]`. Just use `sub.iloc[:, pos]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

This one works without loop and works by applying a **one-index-level** subtrahend on a **two-level-index** dataframe. That way, the subtract() method applies the subtrahend on every row with matching "UpdateTime" index:

```py
df2 = (
    df
    .reset_index()
    .set_index(["UpdateTime", "index"]) # Make a two-level index
    .sort_values(["UpdateTime", "rank"]) # Sort it
)

subtrahend = (
    df2
    .loc[df2["rank"] == 1, 'LapTime']
    .reset_index(level=1, drop=True) # Remaining index level is "UpdateTime"
)

print(subtrahend)
df2["Laptime_Diff"] = df2["LapTime"].subtract(subtrahend)
df2
```

Subtrahend looks like this (Index is UpdateTime, values from LapTime):

```
UpdateTime
162047732    116964
125626988    116683
151851068    116333
```

### This yields:

```
                  CarNo  LapTime   LAPS  rank  Laptime_Diff
UpdateTime index                                           
125626988  7         23   116683   56.0   1.0             0
           13        16   116914   54.0   2.0           231
           8        777   117169   55.0   3.0           486
           12        81   117674   54.0   4.0           991
           11        62   117789   54.0   5.0          1106
           9         31   118919   55.0   6.0          2236
           10       888   119227   55.0   7.0          2544
151851068  14       888   116333  123.0   1.0             0
           16        81   116403  123.0   2.0            70
           18        16   116557  123.0   3.0           224
           19        23   117107  122.0   4.0           774
...
```

## Old solution (using a groupby loop):

```py
dfDict = {}
for name, g in df.groupby("UpdateTime"):
    subtrahend = g["LapTime"].loc[g["rank"] == 1].squeeze()
    dfDict[name] = (
        g["LapTime"]
        .subtract(subtrahend)
        .reset_index().set_index("level_0")
    )

laptimediff = pd.concat(dfDict)

df2 = df.reset_index().set_index(["UpdateTime", "level_0"])
df2["LapTime_diff"] = laptimediff["LapTime"]
print(df2)
```

### Old solutions yields:

```
                    CarNo  LapTime   LAPS  rank  LapTime_diff
UpdateTime level_0                                           
162047732  0          888   119628  147.0   6.0          2664
           1           81   117170  147.0   2.0           206
           2           16   119846  147.0   7.0          2882
           3           62   117178  147.0   3.0           214
           4           31   119516  147.0   5.0          2552
           5           23   117915  146.0   4.0           951
           6          777   116964  121.0   1.0             0
125626988  7           23   116683   56.0   1.0             0
           8          777   117169   55.0   3.0           486
           9           31   118919   55.0   6.0          2236
```

Comment: Yes, it did the work. Thank you. Just one more question, why the rank column don't stay in the order? Is there any way to keep the order, from 1 to 7?

Comment: Reindexing and grouping by a column changes the row order. You can sort the resulting dataframe using  df = df.sort_values(by=[„rank“]). Look up its exact in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), pandas is well documented.

Comment: I edited my answer to yield a nicely sorted result.